# How do I make a function execute on a single item within a mapped array instead of every item in the array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, storybook

I am currently working on a React project and am having difficulty with getting a function to work on a single item within a mapped array.

I have an array of objects in a different file that look like this:

```
export const CUSTOMERS = [
  {
    customer_id: '1',
    name: "John Doe",
    profile_picture: "https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/portrait-white-man-isolated_53876-40306.jpg?size=626&ext=jpg",
    approval_status: false,
    payment_method: Enums.OrderPaymentMethod.IN_PERSON
  },
  {
    customer_id: '2',
    name: "Evan Green",
    profile_picture: "https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/portrait-concept-picture-id1016761216?k=6&m=1016761216&s=612x612&w=0&h=j-DyZTSqmnhoHKsJdGmiMPnungpHiq9UTrvx4UylMQI=",
    approval_status: false,
    payment_method: Enums.OrderPaymentMethod.IN_PERSON
  },
  {
    customer_id: '3',
    name: "Grace Lewis",
    profile_picture: "https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/friendly-brunette-looking-camera_23-2147774849.jpg?size=626&ext=jpg",
    approval_status: false,
    payment_method: Enums.OrderPaymentMethod.IN_PERSON
  }, ...]
```

Currently, I have them mapped out like this:

```
 const displayContacts = () =>
    CUSTOMERS.map((person) => (
      <AvatarContainer onPress={onClickAvatar}>
        <Avatar
          picture={{uri: person.profile_picture}}
          onPress={() => showIcon(person.customer_id)}
        />
        <TextAvatar>{person.name}</TextAvatar>
        {visible && <CheckIcon />}
      </AvatarContainer>
    ));
```

Now, I want to make it so that when I press on a single Avatar, a checkmark comes up to show that I selected that avatar. I am trying to make it so that when I select an avatar, the checkmark displays on the individual avatar.

This is my showIcon function that displays and removes the checkmark on click:

```
const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false);

  const showIcon = () => {
    // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-shadow
    setVisible((visible) => !visible);
    onClickAvatar();
  };
```

Help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So basically you must set which avatar must be "checked" in your state.

```
const displayContacts = () =>
CUSTOMERS.map((person) => (
  <AvatarContainer onPress={onClickAvatar}>
    <Avatar
      picture={{uri: person.profile_picture}}
      onPress={() => showIcon(person.customer_id)}
    />
    <TextAvatar>{person.name}</TextAvatar>
    {visible === person.customer_id && <CheckIcon />}
  </AvatarContainer>
));
```

And here how your `showIcon` should look:

```
const [visible, setVisible] = useState(null);
const showIcon = (id) => { setVisible(id); };
```

If you want your to make a switch:

```
const showIcon = (id) => { 
 setVisible((prev) => {
    return prev === id ? '' : id 
 });
};
```

Comment: Can you explain the state changes in a little more detail? And also thank you very much this works, but now it does select one individually, but how would I now do it so that it also has multiselect where I can select multiple?

Comment: you have an array of items, one of which must be checked, so you must save the id of that item in the state, `null` is a default value for this state, you can also use an empty String it's really up to you.

Comment: Ahh, okay thank you that explains the state very well. However, how would I do a multiselect?

Comment: multiselect - save no just one id in the state, but an array of id's and update them accordingly, then your check will turn from `visible === person.customer_id` to 
`visible.includes(person.customer_id)`

Comment: Okay, thank you and sorry for all the questions, but now the unselect doesn't work, how would I incorporate that in again?

Comment: unselect in case with one item to select must just return the state to its default value

Comment: Updated the answer with "switch" example